# How does C# models get automatically bind with corresponding properties from HttpContent (JSON data)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

My Model Class **ToDoModel**

```
public class ToDoModel
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string  Title { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

My async method

```
private async Task<List<ToDoModel>> GetResponseAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ToDoModel>>());
}
```

I am accessing a sample [Service](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos) which returns data as a JSON array, I want to understand this line

```
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ToDoModel>>
```

When I debug the above line,all the JSON array gets binded in `<List<ToDoModel>>`,I want to know how Model gets automatically binded with corresponding json properties even the property names in json array are different?
In the nutshell my question is how the array object properties  `userId,id,title,completed` binded with My Model Class **ToDoModel** properties

Service is returning data similar to this:

```
 [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  }]
```

Comment: are you asking why it's working or trying to get it to work?

Comment: I want to understand how value is getting binded in model?I got all the values in <List<ToDoModel>> but how it matched with corresponding JSON array that have different name as properties

Answer (score 0):

`ReadAsAsync` is an extension method located in `System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions` (System.Net.Http.Formatting assembly). Basically it creates a C# object from `HttpContent` by matching the property names. The method has some overfloads that accept `IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter>` parameter so you can pass custom formatters.

However, I digged in `HttpContentExtensions` class using ILSpy decompiler and I found that following formatters are used by default:

- **JsonMediaTypeFormatter**
- **XmlMediaTypeFormatter**
- **FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter**

---

Here is some decompiled code from ILSpy:

A parameterless overload of the ReadAsAsync extension method (In HttpContentExtensions.cs)

```
public static Task<T> ReadAsAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)
{
    return content.ReadAsAsync(new MediaTypeFormatterCollection());
}
```

A parameterless contructor (in MediaTypeFormatterCollection.cs)

```
public MediaTypeFormatterCollection() :
    this(MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters())
{
}
```

Private mehod for creating of the default formatters (in MediaTypeFormatterCollection.cs)

```
private static IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> CreateDefaultFormatters()
{
    return new MediaTypeFormatter[]
    {
        new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(),
        new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(),
        new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter()
    };
}
```